# Running periodic Dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have to join data from Google Datastore and Google BigTable to produce some report. I need to execute that operation every minute. Is it possible to accomplish with Google Cloud Dataflow (assuming the processing itself should not take long time and/or can be split in independent parallel jobs)?

1. Should I have endless loop inside the "main" creating and executing the same pipeline again and again?
2. If most of time in such scenario is taken by bringing up the VMs, is it possible to instruct the Dataflow to use customer VMs instead?

Thanks,

Comment: How much data would you join and where would you save the results?

Answer (score 1):

If you expect that your job is small enough to complete in 60 seconds you could consider using the Datastore and BigTable APIs from within a `DoFn` in a Streaming job. Your pipeline might look something like:

`PCollection<Long> impulse = p.apply(
    CountingInput.unbounded().withRate(1, Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
PCollection<A> input1 = impulse.apply(ParDo.of(readFromDatastore));
PCollection<B> input2 = impulse.apply(ParDo.of(readFromBigTable));
...`

This produces a single input every minute, forever. Running as a streaming pipeline, the VMs will continue running.

After reading from both APIs you can then window/join as necessary.

Comment: I could not find UnboundCountingInput.withRate method (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/CountingInput.UnboundedCountingInput#class-countinginputunboundedcountinginput). What is the easiest way to implement such function? Will I need to extend UnboundedSource class or there is some easier way?

Comment: The `withRate` method was added to Apache Beam. You should be able to pass your implementation on that.
https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/CountingInput.java#L195

Comment: And it's being backported in this PR: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/pull/319#issuecomment-229185613